# Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold that is the union of two orientable open submanifolds with connected intersection. Show that $M$ is orientable.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold that is the union of two orientable open submanifolds with connected intersection. Show that $M$ is orientable.

If $M = A \cup B$ with $A$, $B$ orientable and $A \cap B$ connected we have orientation forms $\omega_A, \omega_B$ and I think we can restrict either one of these to $A \cap B$ so that we have an orientation $\omega_{A \cap B}$. If I now set $$\omega_p = \begin{cases} \omega_{A,p}, 
 &p \in A \\ \omega_{B,p}, &p \in B \\ \omega_{A \cap B, p}, &p\in A \cap B\end{cases}$$ this should be an orientation form on $M$?

Comment: How does your proof fail if $A \cap B$ is not connected? If you remove this assumption, the result is no longer true.

Comment: If it's not connected I think we're going to run into some issues with the form $\omega_{A \cap B}$, but unfortunately I don't yet know what might that be. Another idea that occured to me was if I could use the inclusion maps $\iota_A$ and $\iota_B$ and their pullbacks on $M$, but I did not get very far with this. @ElchananSolomon

Comment: You want your $\omega$ to be well-defined, so the restrictions of $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$ to $A\cap B$ should agree. How can you guarantee this?

Comment: @Thorgott That is a good point. Can we use connectedness here or is this route doomed to fail?

Comment: Okay since the intersection is connected it only has two orientations. So either the restrictions of $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$ to $A \cap B$ agree on all points or agree on none. @Thorgott

Comment: Yup, that is correct. If they don't agree, then they are inverse to one another (because there's only two orientations on a connected set and they are inverse to another), so then you can simply replace $\omega_B$ by $-\omega_B$ and are in the case where the two agree. This is the missing step in the argument and I hope also illustrates why the argument can fail if $A\cap B$ is not connected.

Comment: The fact that the two orientation forms coincide on $A\cap B$ is a bit splippy (how can you be sure that this is possible?). To bypass this problem, just glue two (possibly distinct) orientation forms giving the same orientation on $A\cap B$ thanks to a partition of unity subordinate to the cover $\{A,B\}$: something like $\varphi_A\omega_A + \varphi_B\omega_B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the main idea, but failed to rigorously use it: there is no reason for the $\omega$ you defined to be smooth (or even continuous).

To bypass this problem, consider this.
For $A$ and $B$ are open and $A\cup B = M$, $\{A,B\}$ is a finite open cover of $M$.
Let $\{\varphi_A,\varphi_B\}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to this cover.
This means that $0 \leqslant \varphi_A,\varphi_B \leqslant 1$, $\varphi_A+\varphi_B = 1$, $\varphi_A = 0$ on $M\setminus A$ and $\varphi_B = 0$ on $M\setminus B$.

Let $\omega_A$ (resp. $\omega_B$) be a volume form on $A$ (resp. $B$).
Since $A\cap B$ is connected, either $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$ induce the same orientation on $A\cap B$, or they induce opposite orientations.
Up to substituting $\omega_A$ with $-\omega_A$, one can assume the former.
Define $\omega = \varphi_A \omega_A + \varphi_B\omega_B$.
This defines a smooth top-dimensional differential form.
Fix $p\in M$ and $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ a basis of $T_pM$.

1. If $p \in M\setminus A$, then $\omega_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n) = (\omega_B)_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n) \neq 0$.
2. If $p\in M\setminus B$, then $\omega_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n) = (\omega_A)_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n) \neq 0$.
3. If $p \notin (M\setminus A)\cup (M\setminus B)$, then $p\in A\cap B$.
   We have the equality
   $$
   \omega_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n) = \varphi_A(p)(\omega_A)_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n) + \varphi_B(p)(\omega_B)_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n).
   $$
   Notice that $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$ defining the same orientation on $A\cap B$ translates into $(\omega_A)_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ and $(\omega_B)_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ having the same sign, either (strictly) positive or (strictly) negative.
   From $\varphi_A(p),\varphi_B(p) \geqslant 0$ and $\varphi_A(p)+\varphi_B(p)=1$, one deduces that $\omega_p(e_1,\ldots,e_n) \neq 0$.

Finally, $\omega$ is nowhere vanishing, and is thus a volume form.
It follows that $M$ is orientable.